# Sum of many Bernoulli random variable with different amplitude but same success probability

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $Y = a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 + a_3X_3 +....a_nX_n$, where $a_i $ are just constants and  $X_i$ are independent Bernoulli random variables with probability of 0.5. Then what would be the distribution of Y? Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? Its CDF, PDF, characteristic function or if it's a known distribution?

Comment: If $n$ is large, you can approximate it with a Normal distribution.

Comment: Harnak: I want to know the pmf, especially the derivative of pmf near the mean value of Y.  Damien: is this because of the CLT?

Comment: Yes, because of the CLT. Note: when you address a comment to someone, don't forget to provide their name . @Harnak did not receive an alert about your comment to him

Comment: You get a discrete distribution. Difficult to define a derivative of the pmf, except if you use a non discrete (Normal) approximation